# By mistake I have converted an integer to factor. Now I want to restore it

Tags: r

I have loaded a set of data set , in that for catalogs when taken summary it has shown the below

Catalogs

```
 Min.   : 6.00   
 1st Qu.: 6.00   
 Median :12.00   
 Mean   :14.68   
 3rd Qu.:18.00   
 Max.   :24.00
```

I have converted them into factors.

Now when I convert them into numeric or integer

```
summary(Markdat$Catalogs)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   2.000   2.447   3.000   4.000 

> Markdat$Catalogs<-as.integer(Markdat$Catalogs)

  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   2.000   2.447   3.000   4.000
```

Here the original struct has been gone - how to restore it again?

Comment: You could try `as.numeric(as.character(Markdat$Catalogs))`

Comment: You can add a new column containing the data in numeric format